# When I UNWIND an empty array, the parent item doesn't MERGE. How do I get this query to work?

Tags: neo4j

```
UNWIND { newGames } as gameItem
UNWIND gameItem.release_dates as releaseDateItem
UNWIND gameItem.publishersWithName as publisherItem
UNWIND gameItem.developersWithName as developerItem
MERGE (game:Game {id: gameItem.id})
  ON CREATE SET game = {${gameItemTemplate}}
  ON MATCH SET game = {${gameItemTemplate}}
MERGE (platform:Platform {name: releaseDateItem.platform})
MERGE (publisher:GameCompany {name: publisherItem.name})
MERGE (developer:GameCompany {name: developerItem.name})
MERGE (game)-[:RELEASED {date: releaseDateItem.date}]->(platform)
MERGE (publisher)-[:PUBLISHED]->(game)
MERGE (developer)-[:DEVELOPED]->(game)
```

`gameItem.publishersWithName` and `gameItem.developersWithName` can potentially be empty. In such cases, the `Game` doesn't get added.

When I remove all the publisher and developer stuff (or split the queries in 2, but then I have to UNWIND `newGames` twice...), they are added successfully:

```
UNWIND { newGames } as gameItem
UNWIND gameItem.release_dates as releaseDateItem
MERGE (game:Game {id: gameItem.id})
  ON CREATE SET game = {${gameItemTemplate}}
  ON MATCH SET game = {${gameItemTemplate}}
MERGE (platform:Platform {name: releaseDateItem.platform})
```

I'd like to add the `Game` even if the `gameItem.publishersWithName` or `gameItem.developersWithName` is `[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`UNWIND` turns an empty array into 0 rows, that's why the query doesn't continue.

2 solutions :

a) use `FOREACH` instead

b) use a `CASE` :

```
UNWIND CASE length({yourVar}) WHEN 0 THEN [null] ELSE {yourVar} END 
AS it
// continue query
```

NB: will be addressed in [APOC](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/242)

Comment: Hey thanks! They both work great, but is one a better practice over the other?

Comment: Not really, I just prefer UNWIND though, because you can match in it